# How come changing the background-size does nothing, and how can I fix this? Trying to animate the gradient of the box

Tags: html, css

I have 3 boxes on this website that I am creating for myself (LikesBox, DislikesBox, and HobbiesBox in the about me section) the background of the box is a gradient, with some text on top of it (inside the box). I am trying to add an animation where the background of the box slowly changes the gradient. After doing some research I saw that an easy way to do this was to increase the size of the background-image and then transition to different parts of it, but I am unable to change the background-size of the gradient.

I have tried using both background, and background-image, to try and have background-size do something, but neither of them have worked. I am very new to html, and css (began learning them a couple of days ago), so I suspect that there is another part of my code affecting something, or that something is poorly structured which is preventing me from changing the background size.

The navbar, and hero section were created by mainly following a youtube tutorial, then the about me section has just been me going with the flow.

Here is the html, you can ignore everything before the about me section, but I just included it in case it may be affecting something

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Personal Website</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/44c3d7ec8c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar Section (Start) -->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__container">
            <a href="/" id="navbar__logo"><i class="fa-regular fa-face-smile"></i></a>
            <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
                <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="navbar__menu">
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Home </a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> About </a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Education </a>
                </li>
                <!-- <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Skills </a>
                </li> -->
                <li class="navbar__btn">
                    <a href="/" class="button"> Contact </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <!-- Navigation Bar Section (End) -->

    <!-- Hero Section -->
    <div class="main">
        <div class="main__container">
            <div class="main__content">
                <h1>HELLO,</h1>
                <h2>I AM [NAME]</h2>
                <p>A [MAJOR] @ [UNIVERSITY]</p>
                <button class="main__btn"><a href="/">Learn More</a></button>
            </div>
            <div class="main__img--container">
                <img src="images/pic1.svg" alt="pic" id="main__img">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- ABOUT ME SECTION (START) -->

<div class="AboutMe">
    <div class="Header">About Me</div>
    <div class="LikesBox">
        <div class="Likes">Likes:</div>
        <ul class="LikesList">
            <li> <span class="boldWords">Loud chewing</span> - A moment to enjoy the symphony of mastication</li>
            <li> <span class="boldWords">Getting stuck in an elevator</span> - An opportunity to find peace and practice patience</li>
            <li> <span class="boldWords">Traffic jams</span> - A chance to appreciate the beauty of the road and ponder life's mysteries</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="DislikesBox">
            <div class="Dislikes">Dislikes:</div>
        <ul class="DislikesList">
            <li> <span class="boldWords">Chocolate Chip Cookies</span> - No Comment</li>
            <li> <span class="boldWords">Winning 1 million dollars</span> - I would rather win 2 million dollars</li>
            <li> <span class="boldWords">Something</span> - I don't know I couldn't think of a third thing</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="HobbiesBox">
        <div class="Hobbies">Hobbies:</div>
        <ul class="HobbiesList">
            <li> <span class="boldWords">Baking Chocolate Chip Cookies</span></li>
            <li> <span class="boldWords">Cats</span></li>
            <li> <span class="boldWords">Counting Blades of Grass</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="socialscontactresumeBox">
        <a href="Assets/Resume.pdf" target="_blank" class="SocialTags"><button class="resume">Resume</button></a>
        <a href="contact.html" target="_blank" class="SocialTags"><button class="contact">Contact</button></a>
        <a href="https://www..com" target="_blank"><div class="instagram"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></div></a>
       <a href="https://www..com target="_blank"><div class="linkedin"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></div></a>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS, once again you can ignore everything before the about me section, but its included in case something in there is affecting the problem

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

/* Navigation Bar Section (Start) */

.navbar {
    background: #131313;
    height: 110px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

#navbar__logo {
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50px;


}

.fa-gem {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
}

.navbar__item {
    height: 80px;

}

.navbar__links{
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar__btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #f77062;
    color: #fff;
}

.button:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
    color: #f77062;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .navbar__container{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar__menu {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.6s ease;
        height: 50vh;
        z-index: -1;

    }

    .navbar__menu.active {
        background: #131313;
        top: 100% !important;
        opacity: 1 !important;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 50vh;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }

    #navbar__logo {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
        background: #fff;
    }
    .navbar__item {
        width: 100%;

    }

    .navbar__links {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    #mobile-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
    }
    .navbar__btn {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }
    
    .button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
}

/* Navigation Bar Section (End) */

/* Hero Section (Start) */

.main {
    background-color: #141414;
}

.main__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
    margin: 0;
    height: 90vh; 
    background-color: #141414;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

.main__content h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content h2 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.main__content p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}

.main__btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f77062 0%, #fe5196 100%);
    padding: 14px 32px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    outline: none;
}

.main__btn a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main__btn:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
    transition: all 0.6s;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.main__btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.main__btn:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

.main__img--container {
    text-align: center;
}

#main__img {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}

/* Mobile Responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .main__container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        align-items: center;
        justify-self: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 90vh;
    }

    .main__content {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
    }

    .main__content h1 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }

    .main__content h2 {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }

    .main__content p {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .main__content h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin-top: 3rem;
    }

    .main__content h2 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .main__content p {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    
    .main__btn {
        padding: 12px 36px;
        margin: 2.5rem 0;
    }
}

/* ABOUT ME SECTION (START) */

.AboutMe {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #141414;
    position: relative;
}

.Header {
    font-weight: 900;
    position: relative;
    top: 7.5vh;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 7.5vh;
}

.LikesBox {
    height: 55vh;
    width: 25vw;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 10vw;
    top: 23.14vh;
    border-radius: 35px;
    padding-top: 3vh;
    padding-left: 6vh;
    padding-bottom: 3vh;
    padding-right: 3vh;
}

.DislikesBox {
    height: 55vh;
    width: 25vw;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 37.5vw;
    top: 23.14vh;
    border-radius: 35px;
    padding-top: 3vh;
    padding-left: 6vh;
    padding-bottom: 3vh;
    padding-right: 3vh;
}

.HobbiesBox {
    height: 55vh;
    width: 25vw;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 65vw;
    top: 23.14vh;
    border-radius: 35px;
    padding-top: 3vh;
    padding-left: 6vh;
    padding-bottom: 3vh;
    padding-right: 3vh;
}

.LikesList, .DislikesList, .HobbiesList {
    color: white;
    width: 13.5vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    margin-left: 5vh;
}

.LikesList li {
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

.DislikesList li {
    margin-bottom: 7.25vh;
}
.HobbiesList li {
    margin-bottom: 7vh;
}

.HobbiesList li:nth-child(2) {
    margin-bottom: 12.2vh;
}

.Likes, .Dislikes, .Hobbies {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0vh;
    font-weight: 900;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 6.5vh;
}

.boldWords {
    font-weight: 900;
}

.socialscontactresumeBox {
    height: 15vh;
    width: 17.5vw;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #b721ff 0%, #21d4fd 100%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 2.75vh;
    border-radius: 35px;
    padding-top: 2.25vh;
    padding-left: 4vh;
    padding-bottom: 2.25vh;
}

.resume {
    height: 5vh;
    width: 9vw;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
    border-radius: 2.5vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contact {
    height: 5vh;
    width: 9vw;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
    border-radius: 2.5vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.instagram, .linkedin {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 10.6vw;
    font-size: 6vh;
}

.instagram {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.1vh;
}
.linkedin {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7vh;
}

.SocialTags {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend checking out [mcve] and [ask]. Narrowing down the code to just enough to duplicate the problem will assist others in providing the best answers.

Comment: I figure it out, I need to use background-size: 400% 400%; instead of background-size: 400%. Idk why this is the case but if anyone would like to explain, go ahead, but for now my problem has been resolved